# A linear combination of differentiable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Given a $n$ real valued functions $f_1,...,f_n$ each differentiable  on an open interval $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. For each $x=(x_1,..., x_n)$ in the $n$ dimensional open interval 
>   $$S=\{(x_1,..., x_n): a<x_k<b, \text{ k=1 , ... , n}\} $$
>   define $f(x)=f_1(x_1)+\cdots + f_n(x_n)$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at each point of $S$ and that 
>   $$df_{x}(u)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}f'_k(x_k)u_i$$
>   where $u=(u_1,..., u_n)$.

My procedure: We get for each $k$ the formula 
$$f_k(x_k-u_k)-f_k(u_k)=f'(x_k)u_k+u_kE_k(u_k) $$
where $E_k(u_k)$ tends to zero when $u_k\rightarrow 0$. This is possible since $f_k$ is differentiable. Sum for $k=1,...,n$ we have
$$f(x-u)-f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x_k-u_k)-f_k(u_k)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nf'(x_k)u_k+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nu_kE_k(u_k)$$
then I should prove that the quantity
$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{|u|}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nu_kE_k(u_k)$$ 
tends to zero when $u\rightarrow 0$.

How can I do that?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately there is a very simple answer to my problem following another aproximation. I would be happy if some show my why the quantity I said tend to zero directly.

The answer say as follow: Taking $X(x_1,x_2,..., x_n)=x_1+\cdots x_n$ and $T(x_1,..., x_n)= (f_1(x_1),..., f_n(x_n))$ it is clear that both are differentiable function. Then its composition $X\circ T=f$ is differentiable.